# PayPal Express Checkout: Передача дополнительных параметров

Tags: paypal, php

Добрый день. Подключаю платежку `PayPal Express Checkout`, и надо передать дополнительные данные по заказу. В доках написано про такой элемент массива как "Custom". То есть надо просто создать в форме поле с таким именем. Делаю - в результате пусто.
Знает кто-то на счет этого в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если мне не изменяет память, то вы можете отправить CUSTOM значение в процессе `SetExpressCheckout`, эти данные добавляются в `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` и видны они во время ответа PayPal вашему `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`

если только PP не изменил опять что-то, они это любят

Comment: Да, уже нашел этот метод, правда почему то не сработало - данные не вернулись с пейпела - пустой результат в поле. Возможно и я что-то не так сделал..
Но уже решил другим вариантом - просто на моменте сет чекаута записал данные в базу, а на финише их достаю по токену.
Но спасибо, что откликнулись!